# maven linux without download plugins

Tags: java, linux, maven

Im trying to run maven on a linux server that does not have internet connectivity.
I installed maven but when I run "mvn compile"  on my java project, it gets stuck trying to download plugins.
How do I get past it? Is there a place to get a full install with all plugins required so it dosent have to download anything?

[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Cannot access central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) in offline mode and the artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6 has not been downloaded from it before. -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 0):

You can download all jars or import/move them already downloaded from another machine from userHome/.m2 to your ~/.m2 folder, and when you'll try to compile again it'll pull the libs/plugins from m2 folder without trying to download them.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Running Maven does not make sense unless you are connected to a Maven repository.

If you have no internet connection then you need an *internal* Maven repository, i.e. a Nexus or Artifactory server in your company. Now this server does not only provide the dependencies for you, but also the plugins for Maven to run (of course, it has to get them somewhere from, so it needs some kind of connection to the internet).